# What term can I use to express the delay between two connecting flights?

Tags: single-word-requests

What term  can I use to express the delay between two connecting flights in the following situation: I fly down to one airport and wait there without exiting until I take another flight to reach my destination.

Answer (score 17):

> **layover**

is the term for the wait between the arrival time at an airport (not the final destination) and the time of departure.

Comment: wiktionary says a layover is an overnight stop only

Comment: @z7sg: Each to their own. I personally would say *stopover* implies overnighting, but *layover* (standard terminology in the UK bus industry) is usually much shorter, and may only be a few minutes.

Comment: Safety tip: Android phones don't always know this word. Thanks to autocorrect I accidentally texted my wife that I had "a 2 hour lover" in Dallas. Fortunately she was amused. :-(

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just reporting what wiktionary says!  I wouldn't accept such a rule in these cases as someone could mean either thing with both words.  I do prefer the word *stopover* here but not for any particular reason.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: [many other on-line resources](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefreedictionary.com%2Flayover&ei=-0O5TsHbHoKctweHr4HdBw&usg=AFQjCNFH-w_O1gxw0wHVzQ7yfU91HIzY4g) just say "A short stop or break in a journey".

Comment: @Mitch OK.  Do you think we could we change wiktionary?

Comment: @z7sgѪ: I went ahead and [asked a relevant question at meta.ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/taking-action-on-crowd-sourced-on-line-resources-based-on-se-answers). I think wiktionary is wrong, but then what if -I- am wrong.

Comment: Wiktionary *was* wrong. It is fixed now. The business about being "overnight" was erroneous introduced last year and I have reverted it.

Answer (score 6):

In American English, this is often called a [layover](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/layover),

> a short stay somewhere between two parts of a journey

In my experience, it is most commonly used to describe a wait of several hours between flights or trains, during which you often do not or cannot leave the transit hub. *How long is your layover in NYC? Can we meet for lunch?*

*Layover* is sometimes used to describe an overnight stay, but in American English I would tend to ask, instead, *How long are you staying?* if I expected the answer to be that you were staying at least one night.

Comment: +1 for layover, I believe stopover not to be in American usage.

Comment: @Brendon, [stopover](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stopover%2Clayover&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: I like the ngram, but I've never heard the word stopover used in conversation.  Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: An unusual number of birds seem to make *stopovers* in that ngram so I think that might distort the numbers a little too. *Stopover* is definitely attested in COCA as @z7sg pointed out somewhere... I just haven't heard it much!

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+hour+layover%2Cthree+hour+stopover&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthree%20hour%20layover%3B%2Cc0

Comment: (Note that Ngrams doesn't even find "three hour stopoper".)

Answer (score 3):

You can call the wait a [stopover](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stopover).

Comment: you're right about the link. fixed. lone word from where?

Comment: ah i meant all one word ;o) fixed now anyway

Comment: I did see the spelling "stop-over" in at least one dictionary. I'm curious - is this the usual term in British English? I would say "I'm stopping over there for a bit", maybe, but I don't think I've ever called a wait a stopover. (I am from the east coast of the US.)

Comment: @aediaλ I don't think it's exclusively British.  It gets a lot of hits in COCA.  More than *layover*.

Comment: I'm from the east coast of the US as well and I would only say stopover. To me a layover is overnight or at least a long period of time, like 6 hours or more.

Answer (score 0):

The common simple phrase for this situation is being "between flights."

Comment: Hey, what do I know, I've only been a pilot for thirty-plus years? : )

Answer (score 0):

A Layover, in my experience, has always meant a long time between flights (enough to possibly eat, or stay over night in a hotel).

If I'm just changing planes (e.g., Flying from Cleveland to Orlando, but need to catch a connecting flight in Baltimore in, say 1-2 hours), that's merely a "connection."

If I have that same flight, but the time between flights is more like 4+ hours, I'd call that a layover. Overnight is definitely a layover. Airlines call that overnight a "stopover," but to me, it's always been a layover.

Over time, I think the term Layover has come to mean ANY connecting flight, even if it's only 1 minute. I think its meaning has changed over time.